# What is the CA certificate path for a SQL Azure database?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-sql-database, domo

I have a .NET web application which connects to a database hosted in the cloud on Microsoft's SQL Azure platform.  Now I'd like to use [Domo](http://www.domo.com/), a third-party cloud-based business intelligence service, to do some reporting on the data in the Azure database.  The Domo consultant has told me that he needs a CA certificate path for the database server (in addition to other standard connection info) in order to connect to it.  He has suggested that I need to get a cert and apply it to the database server.  However, according to what I have read in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ff394108.aspx), SQL Azure *always* uses SSL; it is not possible to connect to it otherwise.  Given that I am already connecting to it successfully in my application (using Entity Framework 6), there must be a cert already there (Microsoft's), and therefore a certificate path.  **How do I find out what the certificate path is?**  The database server name has the form `xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to confirm that SQL Azure DB always uses SSL and therefore does have a cert already installed.  I found the certificate path by plugging the database server name (xxxxx.database.windows.net) into the online SSL certificate verification tool at DigiCert.com (https://www.digicert.com/help/).  The path was listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

And to take this one step further you can get the path and content of the cert by running the following command through OpenSSL.

```
openssl s_client -connect {yourdbname}.database.windows.net:443 -showcerts
```

Took me awhile to remember how to do that.

Comment: +1 Good info.  I tried this on my mac and it seems to work.  Thanks.